# Update a destination table based on the same data in 3 matching columns in the destination and source field

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have imported data from MS Excel into a staging table in an MS Access database (i.e. tblStagingTable) and will like to transfer imported data into its destination table (i.e. tblPayment) however the destination table contains a foreign key from another table (tblApprovals). I have written an update sql to add the foreign key data into the tblStagingTable using 3 matching columns from tblStagingTable and a query as criteria. Everything seems ok but the update statement is not working, please help me.

```
UPDATE tblStagingTable INNER JOIN
      qryPaymentImport4Approval 
      ON (tblStagingTable.MGL_No = qryPaymentImport4Approval.MGL_Number) AND
         (tblStagingTable.Fiscal_Year = qryPaymentImport4Approval.Fiscal_Year) AND
         (tblStagingTable.Grant_Number = qryPaymentImport4Approval.Grant_Number) 
    SET tblStagingTable.Approval_ID = [qryPaymentImport4Approval].[Approval_ID];
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? Or do you mean it runs but with no rows affected? Try doing a select with your join criteria. Does it match up? You could have a subtle difference in your columns preventing the join

Comment: @LordBaconPants It runs but no rows affected, please can you write an example of the select statement that will update the intended table?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM   tblStagingTable
       LEFT JOIN qryPaymentImport4Approval ON tblStagingTable.MGL_No = qryPaymentImport4Approval.MGL_Number
                                              AND tblStagingTable.Fiscal_Year = qryPaymentImport4Approval.Fiscal_Year
                                              AND tblStagingTable.Grant_Number = qryPaymentImport4Approval.Grant_Number;

Comment: If you run query in Access query window, does it give a number *You are about to update 0 rows*?

Comment: @Parfait i ran the query again in Access and i got a confirmation that it was about to update 47 rows but when i click Yes, i still do not find the new value updated in the column...i have changed the query from INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN

Comment: I am still waiting for help on my question @ Parfait